# Android app not using Application class

Tags: java, android

I added the application to the Manifest and extended the class but something like onCreate won't get used in the class.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Am I missing something? Isn't that all you should do for an application class you use?

Any help is much appreciated. I will probably just begin a new project instead and copy over the code.Manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/smalllogo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
   >
```

Class:

```
import android.app.Application;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
Tracker tracker;

synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
    if (tracker == null) {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1800);

        tracker = analytics.newTracker();
        tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
        tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
        tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);


    }
    return tracker;
}
}
```

And it is telling me getDefaultTracker() is never used...

Comment: We can't debug your code if you don't show it to us. Create the smallest example possible to recreate this issue and post that code here.

Comment: check you import should be like "import android.app.Application;"

Comment: try to give the full path including package name in the manifest for application class.
Also the onCreate method is not visible in your application class.

Comment: Already tried giving full package name what about oncreate?

Comment: where is your onCreate  method???
@Override
public void onCreate() {
 super.onCreate();
}

Comment: Try `.MyApplication` instead of `MyApplication`

Answer (score 0):

All right, I feel really stupid. I have to access this method from another class it isn't automatically used. So I just called on it from another class and it works. Thank you all

Comment: How about using the oncreate in the application class to instantiate this method?